# How to click Mac security alert using applescript

Tags: applescript

I am launching and application using apple script but not able to click on "No" in security prompt" How can we do it?

[image: Attached the image, Here I want to click on No button]

Comment: That's a non-standard dialog, written in java or something? As is, you can NOT access it with your script.

Comment: Its not written in java , it is in objective c only..

Comment: Ah, I can see that your screenshot did not include all of the dialog box, so looked off.  Well, as you can see, the application has no "default" button, so no help there. You can try to use UI scripting to get the button ID, but for a modal box, probably not gonna happen.